# Is this response from the compiler valid?

Tags: swift

The following code invokes an error. I could not find any information on this is in the reference. The lack of whitespace on the right hand side of the '=' operator is an error.

```
let names =["Anna", "Alex", "Brian", "Jack"]
```

Any other combination of this syntax compiles. Anyone know if this is truly invalid syntax per what we know of Swift right now?

EDIT: Error response is: `Prefix/postfix '=' is reserved`

ANSWER: This excerpt seems to answer my question. I just couldn't find it for the longest time:

> The whitespace around an operator is used to determine whether an
>   operator is used as a prefix operator, a postfix operator, or a binary
>   operator. This behavior is summarized in the following rules:
>
> If an operator has whitespace around both sides or around neither
>   side, it is treated as a binary operator. As an example, the +
>   operator in a+b and a + b is treated as a binary operator. If an
>   operator has whitespace on the left side only, it is treated as a
>   prefix unary operator. As an example, the ++ operator in a ++b is
>   treated as a prefix unary operator. If an operator has whitespace on
>   the right side only, it is treated as a postfix unary operator. As an
>   example, the ++ operator in a++ b is treated as a postfix unary
>   operator. If an operator has no whitespace on the left but is followed
>   immediately by a dot (.), it is treated as a postfix unary operator.
>   As an example, the ++ operator in a++.b is treated as a postfix unary
>   operator (a++ . b rather than a ++ .b).

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: The funny thing is that I have this book (it's free on iBooks) and this, what I'd consider as important bit, isn't mentioned until page 807. You'd think they put it somewhere in chapter 1.

Comment: I just had a weird spacing error. Removed all the space between my two operands and typed again

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a space after the `=`. (`=[` looks too sad to be an operator.) It's probably seeing `=value` as a use of a (possible, but not implemented) prefix operator.

Swift isn't entirely whitespace-agnostic like C... in particular, it uses whitespace to distinguish prefix from postfix operators (because `++i++` in C is a grammar oddity). But it's not ridiculously strict about whitespace like Python either.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a space between the `=` and `[`.

When the equals sign is directly in front of the bracket, the compiler assumes that you are trying to perfom a prefix operation on the array.

Answer (score 1):

Place a space between `=` and `[`,

```
let names = ["Anna", "Alex", "Brian", "Jack"]
```

It seems that `=[` is a reserved operator.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to gain some understanding of the error itself.