# Why does != 0 cause a compiler error

Tags: swift

The following Statement causes a compiler error:Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'LogicValue'. In the second line

```
var b=1
if b!=0
{
println("not 0")
}
```

But

```
var b=1
if (!(b==0)) 
{
println("not 0")
```

causes no compiler error.

For what reason 0 can't be compared using the `!=` Operator, but can be compared using the `==` Operator ?What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `!=`, `==`. What do you want?

Comment: I am unsure what the question is, since "!=" is the correct operator to use for "not equal".

Comment: The question was edited. I hope the question is understandable now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to the lack of whitespace around your `!=` operator - Swift is quite fussy about whitespace, and interprets operators differently depending on their surrounding whitespace.

The [language specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/LexicalStructure.html) describes the various rules, although it is not particularly obvious from these that `b!=0` should be invalid.

So you probably need to say `b != 0` rather than `b!=0`

See also: [Is this response from the compiler valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028666/is-this-response-from-the-compiler-valid)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a nice and simple `b != 0`?  It's easy to read and easy to implement.

The reason why the second option works is because the `!` here means "not". So if b equalled 0, the statement would be "not True", or "False".

Answer (score 0):

It's a case of missing whitespace:

```
var b=1
if b != 0 {
    println("not 0")
}
```

compiles fine.