# Swift error: prefix/postfix '=' is reserved

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am getting error message:

> prefix/postfix '=' is reserved

for below simple in swift.

```
var c=0,a=2,b=4
c= a+b
```

any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 18):

Check this:
[Is this response from the compiler valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028666/is-this-response-from-the-compiler-valid)

Swift isn't entirely whitespace-agnostic like C... in particular, it uses whitespace to distinguish prefix from postfix operators (because ++i++ in C is a grammar oddity). But it's not ridiculously strict about whitespace like Python either.

P.S. So you have to add whitespace before =.

Answer (score 2):

If I use a single space after variable "c" name, this error is get removed.

```
c = a+b
```